# How to track custom events with GA4 which is set up in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I currently have set up Google Tag Manager on my website via https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web. So the GTM snippet is in the head of the website.

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Now I want to integrate GA4 into the website but it seems the recommended way to do this is via GTM because you do not need hardcoded `G-XXXXXX` ids anymore.

So adding the following snippet would be unnecessary right? Taken from
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/events?client_type=gtag

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-XXXXX');
</script>
```

And sending custom events to GA4 and this is done via

```
gtag('event', '<event_name>', {
  <event_parameters>
})
```

But how would I send an event to my `G-XXXXX` id using `GTM`? Since I do not have a hardcoded `G-XXXXX` id anymore, how does `GTM` know how to link the event to my `G-XXXXX` id? In the `GA4` snippet there is extra code to set up the id after declaring the `gtag` function but after that is just a `datalayer.push`.

Is GTM setup enough/the equivalent for the standalone GA4 setup?

Comment: Check this post. It could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76075126/given-gtm-installed-ga4-how-to-send-events-via-gtag-without-send-to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will become a very different way than using `gtag` to fire the event.

In GTM

1. Create a `GA4 Configuration Tag`
   [image]
2. Create a `GA4 Event Tag`. You can choose the configuration tag you just created.
   [image]

Then set the event name and the parameters you need. Most important you need to set up the right trigger for it. Like when should the event been sent.

---

Yes it is equivalent like `gtag` at the end. Google just use this user-friendly UI and help to send the GA4 request in the GTM.

---

add-on for click trigger

If you want to capture certain button click

You can use this trigger

[image]

CSS selector would be the most recommend if you know how to use.

Otherwise `{{Click Class}}` or `{{Click ID}}` would also good to use.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How would I trigger this event for a specific case? For example when a user clicks on a specific button?

Comment: update about how to use click trigger. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This confirms my presumption about the custom trigger system which I'm not going to implement it in this way. I've marked it as an answer though.